# Kotlin coroutines dispatcher like Default but without a Main (UI) Thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there a way to create (or get somehow) a Kotlin coroutine dispatcher on Android that acts like Default but excludes touching UI thread cores?

So basically, I am facing a heavy calculation tasks that I want to process with as many CPU resources I can, without them influencing UI performance.

With `Dispatchers.Default` I get the most resources out of the system, but at the same time, my UI makes laggier.

What the best practices can be applied here?

Comment: Rather than `Dispatcher`, you can use `Executers` to provide `ThreadPools`.

Comment: How can I get ThreadPools only touching non-UI CPU cores?

Comment: Check this tutorial : https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/kotlin-coroutines-on-android-things-i-wish-i-knew-at-the-beginning-c2f0b1f16cff

Comment: `Dispatchers.Default` doesn't touch the UI thread. Your UI is laggier because you use 100% CPU. Using another thread pool won't make it any different. No such thing as a "UI thread core".

Comment: So basically you are saying there is no way to make smooth UI+Animations if you are doing heavy lifting? And I cannot ever exclude a core that responsible for UI?

Comment: No, you cannot exclude a core.

Comment: Try to use a pool of size `(coreCount - 1)`.

Comment: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1).asCoroutineDispatcher()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turns out, that my problems solution wasn't in the JVM area but rather in NDK. Native libs was loading CPU to 100% and basically it looks like I can do nothing about that from Java/Kotlin. Looks like answer is somewhere in C code which is out of my competence.

Also I must mention `Executors.newFixedThreadPool((Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1).coerceAtLeast(1)).asCoroutineDispatcher()` solution. It seems to me that it can be helpful for someone have issue with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dispatcher with custom thread pool like this:

```
val threads = 4
val dispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Comment: you could use a thread factory which creates threads with background priority.

Comment: Once you accept that [there is no such thing in Android as a "UI thread core"](https://www.quora.com/Why-android-is-not-designed-with-high-dedicated-priority-thread-for-UI-operations), you'll be in a better position to consider solutions that lead to favorable outcomes.